# Rails not sending session cookies to JSON request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, api, rest, cookies

I am using Rails 3.2.8. I want to access a record from the application do some processing and return the results in the form of a modified record. I am doing this through json requests to the controller. It is working properly, but I get CSRF warnings when I post the update (of course). I thought to remove these by storing the session cookie from the original request and using when doing the post. (This also seems like a good security practice).

The problem is that a session cookie is not being sent. I have tried using HTTParty and RestClient gems. When I make the request in the browser (using RESTClient plugin for firefox) the cookies are sent. I presume that this is the expected behavior as cookies ought to be sent to browsers.

Is there a way to get the cookie to be sent to a script?

Is it correct to do so? and if not how should I be approaching this?

Comment: can you share some code?

Answer (score 3):

Please check the **authenticity_token** goes in the parameters or not. I had faced the similar issue like this in past.

If authenticity_token is not passed in parameter, add in your form form_authenticity_token helper.

or

In your controller

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
```

I think this mights helps you.

Comment: Over 6 years later, this just saved me from a gnarly rabbit hole.  Thanks!